# Django Haystack a good fit for this type of search?

Tags: django, solr, spatial, django-haystack

I have an application that lists jobs within a certain location using spatial search.  It is a fairly simple search with a few filters (date range, job type, etc) no large text to search.  I was considering using something like Haystack with solr to do the search, is it worth the overhead or should I just query the database?

Comment: i am doing the same thing. Django haystack seems so complex for this job. Better use `<Models>.objects.filter(***)`

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing can be easily handled via Solr (or any of Haystack's other backends), but if you start with your database (see [Django Filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) for ideas to make this easy via URLs), and then shift to a search engine when the need arises (based on load), you'll thank yourself later for not introducing more complexity early on.

When you do add the search engine, whichever you use, definitely use Haystack as the API, unless you go with [Sphnix](http://sphinxsearch.com/), in which case maybe see [this blog post](http://eshlox.net/en/2012/09/13/sphinxsearch-and-django-ubuntu/).